# Iterate over subrange of weekdays

Tags: java, dayofweek, weekday

I'm trying to iterate over a range of weekdays, where each weekday maps to an integer `(Sunday = 1, Monday = 2, ..., Saturday = 7)`.

The range is defined by a `start and end day`. This is fine for a start and end day like `Monday(2) - Thursday(5)`, as I can just do:

```
for(int i = startDay; i <= endDay; i++) { ... }
```

I'm having difficulty when the range is split across the end and start of a week, like `Friday(6) - Monday(2)`. This obviously doesn't work with the above for loop - e.g.

```
for(int i = 6; i <= 2; i++) { ... }    // wouldn't even execute once.
```

The only solution I can see is implementing some sort of circular buffer, which I feel is overkill for such a simple problem. I'm just stumped, and most likely missing something obvious here. I think a solution may have something to do with modular arithmetic, but I'm not quite sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
int numberOfDays = endDay >= startDay ? endDay - startDay : 8 - (startDay - endDay);
for (int i = startDay; i <= startDay + numberOfDays; i++) {
    int day = (i - 1) % 7 + 1;
}
```

This makes use of the `%` modulo operator to ensure all values remain within 1 - 7.

For example, once `i` becomes 8 the calculation will wrap `day` back to 1: `(8 - 1) % 7 + 1 == 1`.

Comment: Given a range like `startDay = 6 and endDay = 3`, wouldn't this still not execute at all?

`startDay + (endDay - startDay)` = 
`6 + (3 - 6)` = 
`3`

Resulting in:

`for(int i = 6; i <= 3; i++) { ... }`

Which wouldn't execute?

Comment: Should it be `... 7 - (startDay - endDay);` rather than `... 8 - (startDay - endDay);`? Otherwise it will always add one extra day.

Comment: That depends on what you want and on whether the last day is included in the range.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a % operator for some sort of circularity

```
 for (int i=6; i!=2; i=(i+1)%7) { ... }
```

That will index days from 0, so Sunday = 0 ... Saturday = 6. If you really want to have index starting from 1 it's only interpretation problem. You can for example do:

```
 for (int i=6; i!=2; i=(i+1)%7) { 
     int day=i+1; 
     // use day here
 }
```

Comment: How can this be changed to not index days from 0? i.e. given `startDay = 6 and endDay = 3`, I'd only want to look at day `6, 7, 1, 2, 3`. Not `day 0`

Answer (score 0):

It's probably clearest just to use a `break`, then you don't have to worry about all the different cases:

```
for (int day = startDay; ; day = (day - 1) % 7 + 1) {
    // ... do your stuff
    if (day == endDay) {
        break;
    }
}
```

or, some might prefer this:

```
int day = startDay;
while (true) {
    // ... do something
    if (day == endDay) {
        break;
    }
    day = (day - 1) % 7 + 1;
}
```

or:

```
int day = startDay;
while (true) {
    // ... do something
    if (day == endDay) {
        break;
    }
    if (++day > 7) {
        day = 1;
    }
}
```

Trying to get all the different cases right with a `for` loop can be a headache.  You have to make sure these are handled:

```
startDay == 1, endDay == 7
endDay == startDay
endDay == startDay - 1  (which should go through every day of the week in some order)
endDay > startDay
endDay < startDay
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8:

```
// input section
DayOfWeek start = DayOfWeek.FRIDAY;
DayOfWeek end = DayOfWeek.MONDAY;

// execution section
DayOfWeek dow = start;
DayOfWeek stop = end.plus(1);

do {
  // ... your code
  dow = dow.plus(1);
} while (dow != stop);
```

The do-while-construction ensures that for the condition `start == end` the loop will be executed at least once.

**UPDATE due to use of your localized indices (Sunday = 1 instead of 7)**

You can convert the indices to `DayOfWeek`-objects this way:

```
private static DayOfWeek convert(int localIndex) {
  int iso = localIndex - 1;
  if (iso == 0) {
    iso = 7;
  }
  return DayOfWeek.of(iso);
}
```